# C-Pointers(simple program)

Tags: c, pointers

So I am learning pointers in C right now and there was an example program in the book I'm reading,but it doesn't work right when I run it. The code is:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
     void go_south_east(int *lat, int *lon)
    {
    *lat = *lat - 1;
    *lon = *lon + 1;
}
 int main(){
    int latitude = 64;
    int lontitude = -32;
    go_south_east(&latitude, &lontitude);
    printf("Now at [%i, %i]\n", latitude, lontitude);
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

The idea is that these "latitude and lontitude"are coordinates of an object,and we want to move it south east.I personally think this is the wrong line:

```
 go_south_east(&latitude, &lontitude);
```

Why would we need the address of the variables here ??
And one more question about this line:

```
  printf("Now at [%i, %i]\n", latitude, lontitude);
```

what does %i mean here?Isn't it supposed to be %d for integer value?

Comment: See the signature of the function

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work right when I run it." ? `%d` and `%i` are both format specifiers for integers.

Comment: The program '[6692] korab.c.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
 -This is the message I get

Comment: @user3183584 Exit code 0 means it executed successfully in windows (inferring from the .exe).

Comment: yes I found out,what had misled me.With the return 0; operator the console wasn't opening and all I recieved was the exit code 0,but now I removed the return and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways of passing arguments to a function:

- Pass By Value
- Pass By Pointer
- Pass By Reference

You program is using Pass By Pointer.

Pass By Value looks like this:

```
void go_south_east(int lat, int lon)
{
    lat = lat - 1;
    lon = lon + 1;
}
```

If you change your program to incorporate the above code, you will see the that printf() outputs: "Now at [64, -32]". This is because you passed only the *value* of your lat & lon - actually a copy of their values. The function changes the value of the copy, and does not affect the original.

With Pass By Pointer, you pass to your function the address in memory where the original lat & lon values are stored. The function modifies the data stored at those positions. This is why the current values of lat & lon in main() are changed.

Comment: From the page you linked: "*C does not [...] support pass by reference [...]*"!

Answer (score 2):

```
go_south_east(&latitude, &lontitude);
```

We need the addresses of the variables because you are passing them by reference, because you want to modify their values. You don't want just to give two numbers to the functions, you want it to be able to change them. So you need to inform the function where those variables are located (their addresses) so that the function can modify their values in place.

And it is working right, since the output is `Now at [63, -31]`, so the function correctly red the values passed and updated them.

Comment: There is no "*pass by reference*" in C. You pass in addresses, pointers. Those pointers are passed in by value. However wording "*passing in a reference to something*" would be ok.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking you are right. Anyway often is easier to say "by reference" even if is not 100% correct. From wikipedia: "Pass-by-reference is simulated in C by explicitly passing pointer values."